# Is there a closed form expression for the infinity symbol?

Tags: geometry

I was looking for a closed form expression which plots the infinity symbol.

Comment: Like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli ?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: The Wikipedia page for [the infinity symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_symbol) links to a general page for lemniscates, which includes Bernoulli's along with others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Lemniscate of Bernoulli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli) is a plane curve with a shape similar
to the infinity symbol. It can be plotted  using the parametric equation
$$
x = \frac{a \sqrt2 \cos(t)}{\sin^2(t)+1} \,, \quad y = \frac{a \sqrt2 \cos(t)\sin(t)}{\sin^2(t)+1}\, , \quad 0 \le t \le 2 \pi.
$$
$a$ is half of the distance between the "foci" of the lemniscate.

[image: Image from Wikipedia]

(From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli)

Comment: Why didn't you give the equation as $(x^2+y^2)^2=2a^2(x^2-y^2)$, as given in the article?

Comment: @columbus8myhw: There are several equations given in the Wikipedia article. OP asked for a "closed form expression to plot the infinity symbol", therefore I found the parametric equation most useful in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bit simpler expression (computationally) that yields a similar curve:
$$
x = a\sin(t) \,, \ y = \sin(2t)\,  \quad 0 \le t \le 2 \pi, \quad a > 0
$$
When a=1 the curve looks more like a bow tie, while a=4 renders a curve similar to the Lemniscate of Bernoulli.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way you could put it in your calculator:

$$X(t)=2\sin (t)$$

$$Y(t)=\sin (2t)$$

the reason I say like this is because with my calculator I cannot write 2*sin(t) as
2sin(t) in my calculator, so I just want to give this solution to put the multiplication sign in it. Also If you want a smoother infinity symbol, instead of 2sin(t), do 3*sin(t)(3sin(t)), this will make it bigger but smoother.